# LIMIT command in R RODBC and DBI packages returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, r, syntax

I am trying to query a Microsoft SQL table using the RODBC package.
The following query works fine:

```
data<-sqlQuery(dcs, 'SELECT Classification_Code, Country_Code FROM ICP_Submissions.dbo.ICP_Fact WHERE Classification_Code IN (\'EXP\') AND Indicator_Code IN (\'1000000\',\'1100000\') ')
```

However, if add the command `LIMIT 100` in the following way

```
data<-sqlQuery(dcs, 'SELECT Classification_Code, Country_Code FROM ICP_Submissions.dbo.ICP_Fact WHERE Classification_Code IN (\'EXP\') AND Indicator_Code IN (\'1000000\',\'1100000\') LIMIT 100')
```

I get the following error

```
42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'.
```

I get a similar error message if I use the *dbGetQuery* function of the package DBI.
Any idea of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What's the database? It may require an `ORDER BY` clause before the `LIMIT` clause, or it may be implemented using `TOP`.

Comment: `[ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]`: Two takeaways: (1) SQL Server does not know `LIMIT`, it uses `TOP` instead. Change `SELECT ... LIMIT 100` to `SELECT TOP 100 ...`. (2) That ODBC driver is ancient, you should likely upgrade, there have been a _lot_ of changes/improvements since then.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use SQL Server, you will need to change

```
data<-sqlQuery(dcs, 'SELECT Classification_Code, Country_Code FROM ICP_Submissions.dbo.ICP_Fact WHERE Classification_Code IN (\'EXP\') AND Indicator_Code IN (\'1000000\',\'1100000\') LIMIT 100')
```

to

```
data<-sqlQuery(dcs, 'SELECT TOP 100 Classification_Code, Country_Code FROM ICP_Submissions.dbo.ICP_Fact WHERE Classification_Code IN (\'EXP\') AND Indicator_Code IN (\'1000000\',\'1100000\')')
```

, since `LIMIT` is not SQL Server syntax, it is used by MySQL, for example.